# "Can't set headers after they are sent" error being thrown but no double callbacks

Tags: node.js, express

My code is in two files: `router.js` and `work.js`

Here is the code for `work.js`:

```
getThumbnailItems = function(callback, res) {
        fs.readdir(this.thumbnailPath, function(err, files) {

                callback(files, res);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is where the method is called in `router.js`:

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
    getThumbnailItems(function(items) {
        console.log(items);
        if (res) {
            res.render("home", {title: "The Work Speaks For Itself", items: items});
        }
    }, res)

}
```

I am using a callback in `getThumbnails` to render the `home` view. But an error `"Can't set headers after they are sent"` keeps getting thrown. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Can you provide some more details/source example? I couldn't find anywhere in the provided code that would cause that behavior.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5516529) a simple middleware to debug these issues (as @furydevoid suggests, there's nothing in the code you post that would cause that error).